# Spring MVC + Security. CharacterEncodingFilter doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

I've read all posts here, related to my question and done all what they advice but it wasn't help. I'm new in this direction. I am using spring mvc+security. Here is my code list.

MVC initialize

```
import com.company.bank.config.AppConfig;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.*;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class SpringMVCInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE);

        //Multipart filter registration (WORK's)
        MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
        multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("filterMultipartResolver");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic multipartDecoder = servletContext.addFilter("multipartResolver", multipartFilter);
        multipartDecoder.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        //Decoding filter registration (IT DOESN'T WORK!)
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoder = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        characterEncoder.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        characterEncoder.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        characterEncoder.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
        characterEncoder.setAsyncSupported(true);

        //Creating root Spring context (WORK's)
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ctx.refresh();

        //Dispatcher servllet registration (WORK's)
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
    }
}
```

Security initialize

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

/**
 * Created by OAM on 01.12.2015.
 */
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    //telling spring security to use Multipart Filter before filter chain (for multipart+CSRF) WORK's
    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }
}
```

App configuration

```
import com.company.bank.tasks.rates_updater.JAXB.XMLCurrRates;
import com.company.bank.tasks.rates_updater.RatesUpdater;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Created by OAM on 21.11.2015.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.company.bank")
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RatesUpdater update() {
        return new RatesUpdater("http://pf-soft.net/service/currency/", XMLCurrRates.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter adapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.company.bank");
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(false);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank");
        ds.setUsername("******");
        ds.setPassword("******");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        filterMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000000);
        filterMultipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(10000000);
        return filterMultipartResolver;
    }
}
```

Security conf

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

/**
 * Created by OAM on 01.12.2015.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/client**").access("hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')")
                .antMatchers("/inspector").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and().csrf()

                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/inspector")

                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")

                .and().httpBasic()

                .and().headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(31536000)

                .and().xssProtection().block(false);
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve my problem

Comment: <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />                                                                                                                   all my *.jsp has                                                                               <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: Please state what you are trying to achieve and what the results you see.

Comment: I'am trying to pass cirillic letters and after submit my controller take ???? instead normal letters

Comment: backwards transition work's (DB->WEB)

Answer (score 0):

I would try -

```
    //Decoding filter registration (IT DOESN'T WORK!)
    CharacterEncodingFilter cef = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    cef .setEncoding("UTF-8");
    cef .setForceEncoding(true);
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoder = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", cef);
    characterEncoder.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    characterEncoder.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    characterEncoder.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
    characterEncoder.setAsyncSupported(true);
```

This should ensure the filter has the encoding set

Comment: Unfortunetly it wasn't help. My controller printing on console ???? Method POST in web-form